# Writing timestamps from commands displayed in Jenkins Output Log to either .txt or .CSV file

Tags: python, jenkins, filtering, export-to-csv

I'm relatively new to Python so was wondering if anyone can give some hints or tips regarding something I'm wanting to do using Python whilst being run as part of a build on a Jenkins Pipeline.

To give a basic breakdown I'm wanting to export/save timestamps from the Jenkins Output, which current timestamps all commands/strings that happen within it, whilst it is running a build to either a .txt file or .csv file. These timestamp will be taken when specific commands/strings occur in the Jenkins output. I've given an example below for the Timestamp and Command being looked for.

*"2021-08-17 11:46:38,899 - LOG: Successfully sent the test record"*

I'd prefer just to send the timestamp itself, but if the full line needs to be sent then that would work as well, as the there is a lot of information generated in the console that isn't of interest for what I want to do.

My ultimate goal would be to do this for multiple different and unique commands/strings that occur in the Jenkins output. Along with this, some testing I’d be doing would involve running the same script over and over for a set number of loops, so I’d want the timestamp data to be saved into a singular output file (and not overwritten) or in separate output files for each loop.

Any hints or tips for this would be greatly appreciated as I’ve reached a dead end on what I can search up online involving the use of either the Logging function, using the wait_for_value function to find the required command/string in the console output and then save/print it to a created variable or seeing if Regex would be suitable for the task.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Assuming you are running this command via terminal, you could try writing the output of the file to some file using: ```JenkinsCommand &> SomeFile.txt``` and then, depending on what that output looks like and what you need, parse that file afterward looking for lines that start with timestamps.

Comment: Hi, forgot to include this detail. The python script is being run via Jenkins as part of a Pipeline Build. The pipeline has been set to generate logs as it works, so this is where I found the commands/string of interest. I was originally just going to search the logs to obtain the timestamps I needed, but wondered if I could automate the process slightly by filtering out/saving only the data that interested me to a separate file.